# Use Jfrog Artifactory open source

Tags: artifactory

Since I'm new to Jfrog artifactory. Can you please advice me is it fine if I use Artifactory open source as my production repository manager ?

Since before my company used Apache archiva and i can see there are lot of dependency files deployed into it.

Now i want to move into Aritifactory OSS. can I migrate all artifacts which are in the Apache archiva into jfrog artifactory ?

Please advice.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case that you are only using Maven builds and Java artifacts then the answer is yes, you can use the OSS version of Artifactory. You won't have all of the advanced features that the PRO has to offer. You can see [here](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/versions/) the PRO features.

Regarding your question, importing from Archiva, please follow the instructions as listed [here](https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-import-a-repository-from-archiva/).

Comment: Thank you. But my archiva repository is at remote location from my artifactoy hosted location. In that link which you have mentioned is to import from archiva from the same server which is hosted the artifactoy. Any ideas how can I import all my remote archiva repository into my local artifartifactoy?

Comment: You can either copy the data to the Artifactory server or set the archiva as remote repository in Artifactory.  That way your artifacts will be cached upon request.

Comment: Thank you. I need to shutdown archiva server very soon. so I will try to move all archiva artifacts into artifactory.